# How this code work for other DevExpress Controls (ASPxTextBox, ASPxDateEdit, ASPxMemo)

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

```
for(var i = 0; i < auditControls.length; i++) {
var clientInstanceName = auditControls[i];
window[clientInstanceName].SetEnabled(true);
}
```

Please give me right answer.

Comment: I’m not what you are trying to achieve and therefore I’m not sure what the right answer is. But I  assume that you are iterating over a list of DevExpress controls ClientInstanceNames. You should be able to set the SetEnabled property to “true” for the ASPxTextBox, ASPxDateEdit and ASPxMemo controls. If not please elaborate your question.

Comment: Yes you understand the right thing. i want to set enable, disable all controls as i mentioned, in a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute this code on the client? If so, make sure that you are using the ClientEnabled property on the server to disable/enable controls. Otherwise, if you use the Enabled property, controls won't be rendered at all on the client. Check out [ASPxClientEditBase.SetEnabled Method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientEditBase_SetEnabledtopic) topic.